# javascript regex validation if no content

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following validation on a form field:

```
$(".controlsphone input").blur(function() {
    var ree = /^\d+$/;
    if(ree.test(document.getElementById("register_telephone").value))
        {
            $(this).css('border-color','green');
            $(this).siblings('.info').css('display','none');
            $(this).siblings('.error').css('display','none');
            $(this).siblings('.valid').css('display','inline-block');   
            $("#email_error401112").hide();
            $('#registerErrors').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#registerErrors').show();
        $('#email_error401112').remove();
        $('#registerErrors').append('<p id="email_error401112">Please enter a phone number</p>');
    }
});
```

I would like to only validate the field if a number exists. The field is not required, but if there is content within the field, it needs to be valid (a number)

How does the above code look? Any ideas what i can do to implement this?

Cheers, Dan

Comment: You could also use the `pattern` attribute of input, if your target browsers [support html5 patterns](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-validation-pattern.html): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var ree = /^\d*$/;
```

because `+` stands for one or more, excluding zero.

while `*` stands for zero or more